# CSS Div Alignment Compatibility

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I am having some difficulty with the compatibility of my CSS for the HTML check boxes. For some versions of IE as well as when I place the live html into my PowerPoint, the center div will overlap with the left and the entire page is shifted left. I am not quite sure why this occurs.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}
#googleMap {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}
.Title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#left_check {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
}
#padded-left {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
}
#right_check {
  float: right;
}
#mid_check {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#left_align {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none">

  <div id="left_check">
    <li>
      <form>
        <input id="united_states1" type="checkbox" name="location" value="united_states">United States (domestic)
        <br>

        <div id="padded-left">
          <input id="west1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="west_coast">West
          <br>
          <input id="east1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="central_us">East
          <br>
          <input id="cent1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="east_coast">Central
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div id="right_check">
    <li>
      <form>
        <input id="euro1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="europe">Europe
        <br>
        <input id="africa1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="africa">Africa
        <br>
        <input id="asia1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="asia">Asia
        <br>
        <input id="aust1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="australia">Australia
      </form>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div id="mid_check">
    <div id="left_align">
      <li>
        <form>
          <input id="canada1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="canada">Canada
          <br>
          <input id="centr_am1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="central_america">Central America
          <br>
          <input id="south_am1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="south_america">South America
          <br>
          <input id="ocean1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="oceanic">Oceanic
        </form>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>

</ul>
```

Original CSS (Problems with some pc IE)
[image]

With Flex
[image]

IE Problems (new)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how you can do it, if I got your question right.**

```css
ul {
     display: flex;  
     padding: 0px !important;
}
ul > div {
    /* width: 30%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
}
ul > div#right_check {
    order: 3;
}
ul > div#mid_check {
    order: 2;
}
ul > div#left_check {
    order: 1;
}
div#mid_check li {
    text-align: center;
}
div#right_check li form,
div#mid_check li form {
    text-align: left;
}
div#right_check li {
    text-align: right;
}

form {
    height: 39px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #AFAFAF;
}
div.frame {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<ul style="list-style-type:none">

  <div id="left_check">
    <li>
      <form>
        <input id="united_states1" type="checkbox" name="location" value="united_states">United States (domestic)
        <br>

        <div id="padded-left">
          <input id="west1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="west_coast">West
          <br>
          <input id="east1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="central_us">East
          <br>
          <input id="cent1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="east_coast">Central
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div id="right_check">
    <li>
      <form>
        <input id="euro1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="europe">Europe
        <br>
        <input id="africa1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="africa">Africa
        <br>
        <input id="asia1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="asia">Asia
        <br>
        <input id="aust1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="australia">Australia
      </form>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div id="mid_check">
    <div id="left_align">
      <li>
        <form>
          <input id="canada1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="canada">Canada
          <br>
          <input id="centr_am1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="central_america">Central America
          <br>
          <input id="south_am1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="south_america">South America
          <br>
          <input id="ocean1" type="checkbox" class="location" value="oceanic">Oceanic
        </form>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>

</ul>
</div>
```

**Is this what you trying to get?**
[image]

Comment: Hi, I had tried this first but I would like to maintain the current view of how the CSS appears. If I use flex and 30% width it seems that the checkbox are all towards the left of the page even though the html body should only be 90%

Comment: To clarify a bit I had wanted to have the left div float left, the right div float right, and the mid centered between the two with left alignment.

Comment: How about to change width: 30% to, flex-grow: 1?

Comment: On my screen this answer appears the same as prior. Is it different on yours? Also, thank you for the help!

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I have tried it on IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I can include a picture

Comment: On my laptop this looks pretty similar to what I had before but on other laptops using IE I get the above picture :) I think I am just going to have to deal with having others use another browser.

Comment: quick question on my original CSS tho. I needed to put "left: 10%" in order for the left_check division to be in the right place. Without that statement, the division actually moves right. Any idea on why this is the case?

Comment: It should be right, tried with Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox, I will add picture.

Comment: It would most likely work with edge :) it's just outdated IE that I think is the problem. It looks fine on my personal. Would you be able to answer my other question on my original CSS; I am just trying to learn a bit more.